# MySQL is doing a full table screen

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, explain

I am trying to figure out why the following SQL has a type of ALL for the categories c table.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
 t.todo_id,
 t.name todo_name,
 c.name category_name
FROM
 todos t,
 categories c
WHERE t.category_id = c.category_id
```

The `todos` table has an index on `category_id` and `todo_id` is a primary key.
The `category_id` column in the categories table is a primary key.

The `EXPLAIN` lists `PRIMARY` as a possible key for the categories table but it isn't using it.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the SQL from Jean Louis and the type is still ALL with possible_keys listed as PRIMARY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Your query selects all data from your tables. If you add the WHERE statement everything be fine.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to play around with it some because I have a bunch of where / and clauses but I didn't include them in the example since it's much longer.

Comment: I have created a test database including your tables and tested it. All works fine. Don't care about it. if include the WHERE statement the type is "const". May be the problem is your WHERE statements you did not post here.